# iOS 13 Running on old targets

Tags: swift, ios13

I'm working to update the project to work with iOS 13.

After I updated the carthage the project works fine on the devices with  the latest iOS version.

When I tried to run on a older target I received a lot of errors related to "... is only available in iOS 13" for a lot of situations: layer, some viewcontrollers, custom uiviews .

Project suggestions advice me to add @available(iOS 13.0, *) but without any result.

I made some research and after I tried to add before viewcontrollers:

```
   #if canImport(SwiftUI) && DEBUG
    import SwiftUI
    @available(iOS 13.0, *)
    myviewcontroller 

     #endif
```

I have this problem only in the situations when I try to run on old targets (the project target is 10.0).

I over tried to add @available(iOS 13.0, *) over the method name but still the error persist.
I have over 200 erors like in the image below.

[image]

Comment: Don't use `AnyObject` as the class for `sender`. It's a UIView at least? A UIButton?

Comment: The specific case of `sender.layer` indeed looks very strange, given that `AnyObject` shouldn't have `layer` on any iOS version (and `AnyObject` is almost certainly the wrong type to use here anyway). Could it be that there is some weird extension that adds `layer` and you've manually annotated it to be available for iOS 13+?

Answer (score 1):

If something – a method, for example – is annotated with `@available (iOS 13.0, *)`, you cannot reference it without first checking that iOS 13 is available, such as:

```
if #available(iOS 13.0, *){
    methodRequiringIOS13(…)
} else {
    legacyAlternativeMethod(…)
}
```

or

```
guard #available(iOS 13.0, *) else {
    // Do legacy stuff here
    return
}
// Do stuff for iOS 13+ here
```

Otherwise you will get exactly the error you are seeing when compiling for an older target.

Since it sounds like your codebase already supported older versions, it should be a simple matter of checking what iOS 13 -specific stuff you have added since, and then wrap all of that in these checks. Of course this means you have to provide an alternative legacy implementation for everything until you are ready to up your minimum deployment target, so make sure any new additions are worth the effort.